# While "not equal" is not working as expected

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

While loop is not working as exptected!

Hi everyone,
I wrote this little program where the computer randomizes a number then asks if the number is equal to what the user is thinking.

- if the user types "b" it means that the number that the user has in mind is bigger, so the computer has to guess a bigger number.
- if the user types "s" it means that the number that the user has in mind is smaller, so the computer has to guess a smaller number.
  this will happen until the user types "yes", so the computer should stop guessing.
  But somehow, as the user types "yes" the while loop is not working as expected and guesses another number again, meaning that **"while feedback!='yes':"** is not working properly. Do you guys have any idea what's happening here?

```
import random
range=[0,10]
def do_guess(minimum,maximum):
    print('min is:', minimum, ' max is: ', maximum)
    guess=random.randint(minimum,maximum)
    return guess

def get_user_feedback(guess):
    feedback=input('Is %i correct?'%guess)
    print(feedback)
    while feedback!='yes':
        if feedback=='s':
            range[1]=guess
            get_user_feedback(do_guess(range[0],range[1]))
        if feedback=='b':
            range[0]=guess
            get_user_feedback(do_guess(range[0],range[1]))
    if feedback=='yes':
        print('Wow! you did it!')
        return

get_user_feedback(do_guess(range[0],range[1]))
```

BTW, when I change "while" with "if" the code works just fine!

Comment: You are not really making any use of your loop here. Instead your recursively calling your function. This means when you return, you are returning to the last function call which is still in the loop. You will notice if you type yes on the first attempt that it exists correctly. Get rid of the recursive function calls and maybe restructure it a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are recursively calling the method inside a while loop. So when it returns, it is still running in the loop due to the previous method call. "If" works because it's not looping, rather checking if the program should guess again, or it's the correct guess.